# Properties of a kernel convolution $K'(x,y) = \int_X\int_X K_0(x,a)K(a,b)K_0(b,y)d\mu(a)d\mu(b)$ where $K$ and $K_0$ are kernels on $(X,\mu)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, kernels, integral-kernel, learning-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a probability measure space and $K:X \times X \to \mathbb R$ be a (psd) kernel on $X$. Let $K_0$ be another kernel on $X$ and defined a new kernel $\widetilde K$ on $X$ by
$$
\widetilde K(x,y) = \int_X\int_X K_0(x,a)K(a,b)K_0(b,y)d\mu(a)d\mu(b).
$$

(with obvious integrability assumptions)

> **Question.** *Can the properties of $\widetilde{K}$ (e.g of its induced RKHS, eigenspectrum of induced kernel integral operator, etc.) be deduced from the properties of $K$ ?*

I'm particularly interested in the case where $K$ is an inner-product kernel and

- $(X,\mu) = (\mathbb R^n,(2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-\|x\|^2/2}dx)$, where $dx$ is Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R^n$, OR
- $(X,\mu) = (S_{n-1},\tau_n)$, where $S_{n-1}$ is the unit-sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\tau_n$ is the uniform distribution thereupon.

Comment: Not sure if this helps or is well-known to you anyway. Let $H$ resp. $\tilde{H}$ the RKHS of $K$ resp. $\tilde{K}$. I would expect that $\tilde{H}=\{\int_X K_0(x,a)f(a)d\mu(a) \mid f\in H\}$ to hold under mild assumptions. At least such results hold for differentiation and several other linear operators, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09197 or Lemma 2.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00818.

Comment: It does helps very much. Thanks.